# i want to recover the value of column according to the last date till the date i will insert and want to recover the 2nd maximum salary

Tags: sql, sql-server

employee table amount is `100.62` for `04/04/2013` and `102.62` for `05/04/2013` and so on, so i want to recover the value for amount according to last maximum date and then i want the second maximum incremented salary of the person

and i tried these query till noq for my problem

i am very new in sql server and i write like

```
select amount from employee where max(date)<=15/04/2013
```

and

```
select top1 from employee(select top2 from employee order by salary desc) order by salary
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OFFSET FETCH Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx). For example your second query could be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```